# GWT Async Callbacks

Tags: javascript, gwt, asynccallback

I am working on this piece of GWT code that has a method that accepts a callback function as an argument:

```
    service.XYZ(new AsyncCallback(){
         public void onSuccess(){
             //Does something
         }

         public void onFailure(){
             //Does something
         }
    });
```

Is there a way to execute onSuccess immediately and not at a later point in time? (Assume that method XYZ's signature cannot be changed). Also, if I could define the AsyncCallback function myself, and if I could execute the onSuccess method immediately like so - callback.onSuccess() - how do I pass arguments to callback.onSuccess method? Currently the argument to the onSuccess method is available only within method XYZ.

Comment: Well, the whole point of an async callback is to get executed later, when the request is completed (eg. you obtain some resultset and pass it to another method). For the immediate execution I guess you should then use a regular (non-async) method.

Answer (score 0):

First off: what you want to do is most probably wrong and you should re-evaluate how things are done.

Once said that, and limiting ourselves to your restrictions:

```
final Object fixedArgument = ...;
final String[] variableArgument = { "Sample argument" };
AsyncCallback myCallback = new AsyncCallback() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess() {
         //Does something like fixedArgument.toString() or variableArgument[0].isEmpty()
     }

     @Override
     public void onFailure() {
         //Does something
     }
};
service.XYZ(myCallback);
myCallback.onSuccess();
// fixedArgument = new Object(); Cannot do this
variableArgument[0] = "Another sample argument";
myCallback.onSuccess();
```